# Organize counter (newtheorem)

Tags: theorems, counters, newtheorem

I'm writing some notes and I have a problem with the organization. I defined the theorems as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theo}[teo]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{coro}[teo]{Corolary}
\newtheorem{lema}[teo]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[teo]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{df}[teo]{Definition}
\newtheorem{ex}[teo]{Example}
\newtheorem{obs}[teo]{Remark}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

In the text, theorems, definitions, propositions etc are in the same "counter". I mean

**Theorem 1.5**

**Proposition 1.6**

**Example 1.7**

I want to organize as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theo}[teo]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{coro}[teo]{Corolary}
\newtheorem{lema}[teo]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[teo]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{df}[teo]{Definition}
\newtheorem{ex}[teo]{Example}
\newtheorem{obs}[teo]{Remark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{ONE}

  \section{1}

     Proposition 1
     Theorem 1

  \section{2}

     Theorem 2
     Example 1

\chapter{TWO}

  \section{1}

     Proposition 1
     Theorem 1

  \section{2}

     Theorem 2
     Example 1


\end{document}
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: If I understand well, all theorem-like environment should each have its own counter, which should be reset per chapter?

Comment: @Bernard, yes, exactly! I did not want the theorems to be linked sections, only chapters, but I don't want to use the chapter counter too, I mean "Theorem 1.1". Just "Theorem 1" and restarting in each chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are: remove the optional `[teo]` everywhere, replace  the optional [section]`with`[chapter]`, and redefine`\theteo`, &c., so it doesn't include the chapter number as a prefix.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lema}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]

\renewcommand{\theteo}{\arabic{teo}}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{theo}}
\renewcommand{\thecoro}{\arabic{coro}}
\renewcommand{\thelema}{\arabic{lema}}
\renewcommand{\theprop}{\arabic{prop}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{df}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{obs}{Remark}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thedf}{\arabic{df}}
\renewcommand{\theex}{\arabic{ex}}
\renewcommand{\theobs}{\arabic{obs}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{ONE}

  \section{1}
    \begin{prop}
         Proposition 1
    \end{prop}
     \begin{theo}
     A first theorem
    \end{theo}

  \section{2}

     \begin{theo}
     Another theorem
    \end{theo}
    \begin{ex}
      A funny example.
    \end{ex}

\chapter{TWO}

  \section{1}

    \begin{prop}
         Another proposition.
    \end{prop}

     \begin{theo}
     A first theorem in chap. two
    \end{theo}

  \section{2}

     \begin{theo}
     A second theorem in chap. two
    \end{theo}
    \begin{ex}
      A silly example.
    \end{ex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got it, perfect! Thank you! A curiosity: using rennewcommand, is possible remove the numbers of theorem-like?

Comment: I think you should define a new theorem style. Package `thmtools` may help. Other than that, `ntheorem` has built-in `nonumberplain` and `nonumberbreak` theorem styles.